# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Spark: 2.4.4
Pyspark

I have registered temp table and trying to save output to a csv file.
but getting error as 
**"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'"**

```
data.registerTempTable("data")
output = spark.sql("SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM data").show(truncate = False)

output.write.format('.csv').save("D:/BPR-spark/sourcefile/filtered.csv")
```

please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning the result of *show()* to the variable *output* and *show()* doesn't return a value.

So, you want to assign the Dataframe to the variable `output`, and then saving it like this:

```
data.registerTempTable("data")
output = spark.sql("SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM data")
output.write.format('.csv').save("D:/BPR-spark/sourcefile/filtered.csv")
```